# Determine if a NIC has Internet access (vs local, closed network)

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, network-adapter

Is there some way in PowerShell to automatically determine which of multiple NICs has Internet access rather than an connection to a closed network?

Say, a computer has one NIC that can generally get out to the Web and another NIC that is connected to a small, scientific device network.  They both have IP addresses and see a "network".  Is there a generic way to determine which is *Internet* connected?

I know about:

```
gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'"
```

and

```
gwmi win32_networkadapter -filter "NetConnectionStatus LIKE '2'"
```

and

```
Get-NetAdapter | ? {($_.status -eq 'up')
```

but it's not clear to me that those filters are identifying *Internet* access vs just network access, and unfortunately, I don't have access to a machine with that kind of setup to test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Test-Connection` cmdlet allows you to specify the source address with the `-Source` parameter. We can test the addresses being used by each adapter.

```
$adapters = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily ipv4 | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -in (Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) | Select-Object IPAddress,InterfaceAlias

$adapters | % {

    Test-Connection -Source $_.IPAddress -Destination 8.8.8.8 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null

    if($?) {
        write-host $_.InterfaceAlias "(" $_.IPAddress ") can connect to the internet."
    }
    else {
        write-host $_.InterfaceAlias "(" $_.IPAddress ") failed to connect to the internet."
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Local Area Connection ( 10.1.1.2 ) can connect to the internet
Ethernet 2 ( 10.1.1.3 ) failed to connect to the internet.
Wireless Network Connection ( 10.1.1.4 ) failed to connect to the internet.
```

Comment: I didn't realize `test-connection` had a `-source` option.  That is exactly what I was looking for!  Unfortunately, `-source` and `-quiet` cannot both be used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best way would be to check which adapter the default route use.

```
Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix "0.0.0.0/0"
```

This would give you the `ifIndex` for the adapter that should be connected to the internet. The same `ifIndex` can be used to get the adapter...

```
Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex <number from previous command>
```

Comment: Are you certain that default route can't be assigned to NIC that isn't connected to internet? I faced issue with that in Linux previously, default route was assigned based upon which NIC was enabled first. I suppose Windows might have it handled...

Comment: Well, the default route is where all traffic goes, unless it is specified in the routing table.. So if the default route points to an internal network, you won't have access to the internet at all.. :)  (There might be several default routes, though.. Just different priorities)

Comment: You could also use something like `Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8` to get the index of the interface that would route the traffic to that IP.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to disable Internet access while leaving local network connections alone.  Once I disable the default route NIC, the next NIC becomes default (I assume).  Although it would be rare, I can't assume only two NICs (one online, and one local), so I have to iterate through all the "up" status NICs.